# How to install and load library in R from web server(cgi-bin)?

Tags: r, linux, apache, cgi-bin

I am trying to generate a heatmap for a data using R with pheatmap library in apache web server using Cgi-bin. The library `pheatmap` is installed on the machine where I am running the Cgi-bin, but when I try to load the library from the server it says library pheatmap not installed.
with rscript.sh I pass the r script to run in server

`rscript.sh` code:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
exec 2>&1
echo -n "Generating heatmap: "
R < heatmap.R --save
```

`heatmap.R` code:

```
library(pheatmap)
t1 <- read.table(".tsv", header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
pdf(".pdf")
pheatmap(t2)
dev.off()
q()
```

How to  install and load the library?

Comment: as the web-server user or as root, startup R on the command line and `install.packages("pheatmap")`

Comment: in root pheatmap is already installed

Comment: then your web server may be sandboxed/jailed and not able to access it. you should prbly have a separate pkgs library for your web server and this question now is prbly better served on serverfault http://serverfault.com/